# TYPO3: Get rootline level with page ID in fluid - maybe in viewhelper

Tags: typo3, fluid

i want to get the rootline level from an page with the ID X.
For example: Page2.1 with the ID 233 -> rootline level = 4.

From this point, i want to get the page id from the parent page in the rootlevel 2.

The reason:
I have a multilanguage webpage with many childpages - like this example:

```
[root]
 |- Umbrella Brand-1
   |-country1
      |-page1[200] -> relation to page1[400]
      |-page2[201]
         |-page2.1[203] -> relation to page 2.1[233]
      |-page3[202]
   |-country2
      |-page1[230]
      |-page2[231]
         |-page2.1[233]
      |-page3[232]
|- Umbrella Brand-2
   |-country1
      |-page1[400]
      |-page2[401]
         |-page2.1[403]
      |-page3[402]
   |-country2
      |-page1[430]
      |-page2[231]
         |-page2.1[233]
      |-page3[232]
```

I want to build relation between pages in diffrent countrys, maybe it's a about page. With this relations, i build an country select menu. Here is the background, that by an countrychange the same page open, from where i come. For example: page1[200] -country change->page1[400].

I hope that anyone know what i mean. 
Sorry for this bad english.

Answer (score 0):

the TSFE will give you the pagelevel, but I sill dont see how this will work.
If your pages are out of sync, you will loose your link.

Don't understand why you would like to build separate 'sites' for each brand? Only reason would be that they have completely separated content, templates etc.

You could use the languages as country / brand selection. nobody said that the swebsite languages need to be used for languages.
for ex: brand1 / country1 would have lang uid 1
This way you can add all your content on 1 site.
If you need different styling / templates, settings then all can be set by the sys_lang_uid.

Comment: Hello,
you can switch from the page (for ex. about us) at the page tree "umbrella brant-1" with a selection to every other umbrella brand, for ex. umbrella brand-2. This websites with this umbrella-brands have different languages. For ex. brand-1 have de, fr and nl. The brand-2 site have es, tr and us. 

My part for this task is to build an selection menu, that are linked to every other brand and to the same site / to the linked page in the other brand.